# How to invoke CefV8Context::Eval() method in browser process?

Tags: c++, chromium, chromium-embedded

I want to invoke CefV8Context::Eval function and get the returned value in browser process's UI thread. But the CEF3 C++ API Docs states that V8 handles can only be accessed from the thread on which they are created. Valid threads for creating a V8 handle include the render process main thread (TID_RENDERER) and WebWorker threads. Is that means I should use the inter-process communication (CefProcessMessage) to invoke that method and get the return value? If so, how to do this in synchronous mode?

Comment: I am not sure why the question is downvoted. It shows a clear understanding of the problem and some research - I've edited the question to attempt and make this more evident. As such, I'm upvoting it and would be happy to hear the downvoter's line of thought?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: `CefFrame::ExecuteJavaScript` for simple requests will work. For more complex ones, you have to give up one level of synchronousness or use a custom message loop.

---

What I understand you want to do is to execute some Javascript code as part of your native App's UI Thread. There are two possibilities:

1. It's generic JS code, doesn't really access any variables or functions in your JS, and as such has not *context*. This means Cef can just spin up a new V8 context and execute your code - see `CefFrame::ExecuteJavaScript()`. To quote the examples on [CEF's JS Integration link](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration):

   CefRefPtr browser = ...;
   CefRefPtr frame = browser->GetMainFrame();
   frame->ExecuteJavaScript("alert('ExecuteJavaScript works!');",
       frame->GetURL(), 0);
2. It's JS code *with a context*. In this case, read on.

**Yes** - CEF is designed such that only the RenderProcess has access to the V8 engine, you'll have to use a `CefProcessMessage` to head over to the Browser and do the evaluation there. You sound like you already know how to do that. I'll link an answer of mine for others who don't and may stumble upon this later: [Background process on the native function at Chromium Embedded Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244592/background-process-on-the-native-function-at-chromium-embedded-framework)

**The CEFProcessMessage from Browser to Render processes is one place where the request has to be synchronized.**

So after your send your logic over to the render process, you'll need to do the actual execution of the javascript code. That, thankfully, is quite easy - the same JS integration link goes on to say:

> Native code can execute JS functions by using the ExecuteFunction()
>   and ExecuteFunctionWithContext() methods

The best part - the execution seems to be synchronous (I say seems to, since I can't find concrete docs on this). The usage in the examples illustrates this:

```
if (callback_func_->ExecuteFunctionWithContext(callback_context_, NULL, args, retval, exception, false)) {
  if (exception.get()) {
    // Execution threw an exception.
  } else {
    // Execution succeeded.
  }
}
```

You'll notice that the second line assumes that the first has finished execution and that the results of said execution are available to it. So, **The CefV8Value::ExecuteFunction() call is by nature synchronous.**

So the question boils down to - *How do I post a CefProcessMessage from Browser to Renderer process synchronously?*. Unfortunately, the class itself is not set up to do that. What's more, the [IPC Wiki Page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication#Synchronous_messages) explicitly disallows it:

> Some messages should be synchronous from the renderer's perspective.
>   This happens mostly when there is a WebKit call to us that is supposed
>   to return something, but that we must do in the browser. Examples of
>   this type of messages are spell-checking and getting the cookies for
>   JavaScript. Synchronous browser-to-renderer IPC is disallowed to
>   prevent blocking the user-interface on a potentially flaky renderer.

Is this such a big deal? Well, I don't really know since I've not come across this need - to me, it's ok since the Browser's message loop will keep spinning away waiting for something to do, and receive nothing till your renderer sends a process message with the results of JS. The only way the browser gets something else to do is when some interaction happens, which can't since the renderer is blocking.

If you really **definitely** need synchronousness, I'd recommend that you use your custom MessageLoop which calls `CefDoMessageLoopWork()` on every iteration. That way, you can set a flag to suspend loop work until your message is received from renderer. Note that `CefDoMessageLoopWork()` and `CefRunMessageLoop()` are *mutually exclusive* and cannot work with each other - you either manage the loop yourself, or let CEF do it for you.

That was long, and covers most of what you might want to do - hope it helps!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I can do that asynchronously by sending the js code to render process and execute it and then send back the result to browser process. In CefClient::OnProcessMessageReceived() callback I can get the result but this callback is called in the next (or next next, it doesn't matter) message loop iteration which is not suitable for my program. What I want is that sending the js code and getting the result can be wrapped in one c++ function.

Comment: @Kery Please see the last part of my answer on `CefDoMessageLoopWork()`. Would that help you?

As an aside, I do agree with the docs that if you need this kind of synchronousness, you're either deep enough to warrant a custom message loop, or need a re-look at code structure...

Comment: Thanks! Running another message loop works! Firstly, I define a flag variable, reset this flag before sending message to render process and set the flag when received the message which contains the return value from js execution. In the c++ method (which sending message to render process) use a while loop to check that flag, call CefDoMessageLoopWork() until that flag is set.

Comment: But this introduced another small problem that it seems CefDoMessageLoopWork can't work with CefRunMessageLoop, so I have to use CefDoMessageLoopWork instead of CefRunMessageLoop in the main loop.

Anyway, it works! Thanks again!

Comment: @Kery Yes, the two are designed to be mutually exclusive. I'll add this to the answer - thanks for pointing it out. If this worked for you, please accept so people know it's resolved. Happy to help!

Comment: Sorry! I can't login my account at home yesterday.

My final solution is keep the CefRunMessageLoop call in main loop because I don't want to care how frequently I should call CefDoMessageLoopWork. And also, run a deeper message loop (still use CefRunMessageLoop) after sending message to render process. When the returned message received, call CefQuitMessageLoop so that the deeper message loop can quit.

Comment: @Kery That's a nice workaround - I am not sure how this is treated in the docs (multiple message loops on the same thread), hence my reference to it as a workaround. If you see any relevant docs, please link them here.